# Docker warning on cgroup swap limit, memory.use_hierarchy

Tags: grub2, kernel, swap, docker

I am getting this warning from 'sudo docker -d':

> WARNING: Your kernel does not support cgroup swap limit.

even after following the steps (as in this [link](https://docs.docker.com/installation/ubuntulinux/)):

- modify below lines in /etc/default/grub (I did both for good measure)

  > RUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFUALT="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
  >   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1"
- and then update-grub/reboot via

  > sudo update-grub; sudo reboot

**My questions are:**

**1) Should I be worried about this warning?**

I think I should be because I am trying to use docker containers in a use case where enforcing memory limits is important.

**2) Is it a good idea to change the memory use_hierarchy setting? -- or -- What is the best way to fix this?**

I see this warning in 'dmesg'. I am not sure if it is a good idea to try to change the use_hierarchy setting to '1' (nor how exactly to do this)

> cgroup: "memory" requires setting use_hierarchy to 1 on the root."

Or, is there some better way to fix this? I'm just firing wild shots here, perhaps a kernel upgrade would help? I see some 3.16 kernel upgrades are possible.

**Environment:**
I am running Ubuntu 14.04 x64 (kernel: 3.13.0-43-generic x86_64) with docker version 1.0.1

**Other notes:**
I have read other online help articles about similar docker/cgroup errors that say installing apparmor_parser fixes it. However, on my system, apparmor is installed and appears to be started up just fine (per dmesg). Also, this file exists: /sbin/apparmor_parser

Also, I'm rather new to admin tasks on linux servers.

(cross posted from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838809/docker-warning-on-cgroup-swap-limit-memory-use-hierarchy))